# Python requests.post not working with vulnerable web app login.php

Tags: python, scripting, python-requests

I am trying to login to http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php, with Python requests.post method.

Currently I am doing as follows:

```
import requests
payload = {'username':'admin','password':'password'}
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php', data=payload)
```

However it does not seem to be working. I should be getting a 301 status code from the response object, but I am only receiving 200 codes. I've also taken the cookies from my browser and set them in the requests object; however, this does not work, and also defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do.

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php",auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin','password'))
```

and

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
cookies = {'PHPSESSID':'07761e3f52ae72fa7d0e2c57569c32a7'}
response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php",auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin','password'),cookies=cookies)
```

None of the above methods give the result I require/want, which is simply logging in.

Comment: You should check `response.history`

Answer (score 1):

By default, requests will follow redirects. `response.status_code` will be the status code of the ultimate location. If you want to check if you've been redirected, look at `response.history`.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://google.com/") #301 redirects to 'www.google.com'
response.status_code
#200
response.history
#[<Respone [301]>]
response.url
#'http://www.google.com/'
```

Additionally, a good way to have `requests` keep track of your session/cookies is by using `requests.Session`

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as sesh:
    sesh.post(the_url, data=payload)
    #do more stuff in session
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your answer, however I found my answer question. It is as follows in case anyone else has the same issue.

instead of:

```
import requests
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php',data={'username':'admin','password':'password'})
```

You also need the login token stored in the payload, as follows:

```
import requests
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php',data={'username':'admin','password':'password','Login':'Login'})
```

It then logs me in correctly.